# Copy /b all files of a type except two

Tags: javascript, batch-file, text, automation, concatenation

copy /B src\starting.js+src*.js+src\ending.js /D build\library.js

here's my code. how can I copy all files but starting and ending .js into a text file between the contents of starting.js and ending.js?

for example:

if starting is:

```
first
```

if ending is:

```
last
```

if filler and filler 2 and filler 3 is:

```
filler
```

Then the output is:

```
      first
      filler
      filler
      filler
      last
```

Comment: are `starting` and `ending` fixed names? How can I recognize the last and the first file? They can be ordered by different criteria - alphabetically , by time , by zise ...

Comment: and for the filler files - again - how the should be ordered ? or there's no matter?

Comment: starting and ending are fixed names. Ordering dosn't matter except starting is first and ending is last. Thanks! @npocmaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "files_dir=C:\src\"
set "result_file=C:\buid\lib.js"

pushd %files_dir%


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "copy_list=+"

for %%f in (*) do (
    if "%%~nf" NEQ "starting" if "%%~nf" NEQ "ending" (
        set "copy_list=!copy_list!"%%~nxf"+"
    )
)

copy /B starting.js!copy_list!ending.js /D %result_file%
popd
endlocal
```